# встраиваемый код и chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

Добрый день. Знакомлюсь с созданием chrom расширений и столкнулся с непониманием принципа расширений. 
Задача: По нажатию на кнопку с id="btn" вытащить текст из блока с id="content"
Для теста есть простая html страница:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="content">Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот сам манифест:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Just a simle extension",

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",  
        "activeTab"

    ],

    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
        "js": [ "popup.js" ],
        "css": [ "style.css" ],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }
], 

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "test",
        "default_icon": "ico/icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "options_page": "options.html"
}
```

Вот код popup.js:

```
window.onload = function () {
var get = function (id) {

        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

get("btn").onclick = function () {
    var txt = document.getElementById("content");
    alert(txt.innerHTML);

}


}
```

Объясните пожалуйста, почему не работает. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score -2):

@Asantasan, Вы забыли в html сослаться на popup.js

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="content">Text</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Также в манифесте в "content_scripts": вы указываете popup.js, хотя по умолчанию он не относится к контентному скрипту.

Comment: Если на то пошло, то и кнопку забыл поставить )